# What is the value of $n \aleph_0$ when $n$ is a finite cardinal number?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, cardinals

My professor asked us to think about this question:
If $n$ is a finite cardinal number, what is the value of $n \aleph_0$?

I think that the answer is $\aleph_0$ again. We had a similar property in addition.
If $\aleph_0$ is the cardinal number of the natural numbers and $n = card \{x_1, x_2,...,x_n\}=X$ then $n\aleph_0$ is the cardianl number of the cartesian product of $X$ and the set of natural numbers.
Then to prove my guess I need a function that is surjective and injective from the natural numbers to $X \times \Bbb N$.
Right? Can someone give me a hint how to find such function? (If my guess is right) Or is there a better approach to solve such questions?

Comment: Your guess is correct.  My suggestion is to proceed by induction on $n$.  That reduces the problem to finding a bijection $f:2 \times \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$.

Comment: I guess we assume AC, so we do not have to worry about "Dedekind finite" cardinals.

Comment: If you want an explicit bijection, euclidian division by $n$ can do the trick.